# SQL how to select if last 5 outcomes are the same

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    phone_number, system_outcome, timestamp_dtm, 
FROM 
    call_stats_view 
WHERE 
    DATE (timestamp_dtm) BETWEEN '2016-12-23' AND '2016-12-31'
    AND system_outcome = 'NO_ANSWER'
GROUP BY 
    phone_number
HAVING 
    COUNT(Phone_number) > 6
```

This is what I have at the moment but I need to select only where count of phone number with no answer is 7 or more in a row

Table name is `call_stats_view`.

- Column 1 - Phone_number
- Column 2 - System_outcome

Sample data:

```
Phone_number      System_outcome
--------------------------------
07777778999       Answered
07777778123       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778124       No Answer
07777778128       Answered
07777778074       Answered
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server and if yes, what version?

Comment: do you have any primary key like id

Comment: Who does your question relates to the topic?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL workbench

Comment: In such case you must use the cursor and count the System_outcome string accordingly ..

Answer (score 0):

You want to:

`GROUP BY phone_number, system_outcome`